# Anti-Cauchy Sequences

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

We say a real valued sequence $(a_{n})_{n\geq0}$ is **anti-Cauchy** if $\forall\varepsilon>0$, there exists some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that :
$$
|a_{n}-a_{m}|>\varepsilon\quad\forall m,n>N,\;m\neq n
$$
For natural numbers K, we define the $K^{th}$ difference sequence $D_{i}(k)$ of a sequence $a_{n}$ and the $K^{th}$ sum sequence $S_{i}(k)$ of a sequence $a_{n}$ as follow : (note that $i\geq0$)
$$
\begin{align}
D_{i}(k)=&
\begin{cases}
D_{i}(0)=a_{i}\\
D_{i}(k+1)=D_{i+1}(k)-D_{i}(k)&\text{for $k\geq0$}
\end{cases}
\\
\\
\qquad
S_{i}(k)=&
\begin{cases}
S_{i}(0)=a_{i}\\
S_{i}(k+1)=\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^{i}S_{r}(k)&\text{for $k\geq0$}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$
$1)$ Does there exist for each natural number $K$, a sequence such that its $k^{th}$ difference sequence is actually anti-Cauchy if and only if $k\leq K$ ?

$2)$ Does there exists a real valued sequence, not identically $0$ such that its $K^{th}$ sum sequence is never anti-Cauchy for any natural $K$?

### UPDATE :

I would like to thank **mathworker21** for his partial answer, I would also thank for T.H. Shehadi for his guess for part $(1)$ yet I am unsure if it is a correct answer or not I am still looking for a credible answer for $(1)$.

### PROPOSITION :

**T. H. Shehadi** has offered an alternative definition for the $K^{th}$ difference sequence and $K^{th}$ summation sequence that would describe difference sum an in terms of partial sum I hope it could help in solving $(1)$  :

> $(1)$ : Let Λ map sequences to sequences so that $\Lambda(a_{0})=a_{0}$ and $\Lambda(a_{n+1})=a_{n+1}−a_{n}$. We say that $\Lambda^{k}(a)$, i.e. $\Lambda$ composed with itself $k$ times, is the $k^{th}$ difference sequence of $a$.

> $(2)$ : Let $\Omega$ map sequences to sequences such that $\Omega(a_{n})=a_{0}+a_{1}+\cdots +a_{n}$. We say that $\Omega^{k}(a)$ i.e. $\Omega$ composed with itself $k$ times, is the $k^{th}$ summation sequences of $a$ where $\Omega^{0}(a)=a$

Comment: For $(1)$, $a_{i}=i^2$?

Comment: Take a look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence

Comment: Should your definition include $m\ne n$? If not, then clearly no sequence is anti-Cauchy, since $\lvert a_n-a_n\rvert=0$

Comment: Yess they should be distinct, I will fix that right away

Comment: I am curious to know how $(2)$ would be solved.

Comment: @T.H.Shehadi see below

Comment: That's a great answer I think OP should award you bounty @mathworker21

Comment: @WiWo  , I was thinking can you modify your definition of a difference sequence slightly so that users can open up the option to study anti-Cauchy sequences in terms of partial sums instead?

Comment: Ofcourse but at the moment I have no knowledge of such definition other than this.

Comment: Let $\Lambda$ map sequences to sequences so that $\Lambda(a_{0}) = a_{0}$ and $\Lambda(a_{n + 1}) = a_{n + 1} - a_{n}$. We say that $\Lambda^{k}(a)$, i.e. $\Lambda$ composed with itself $k$ times, is the $k^{th}$ difference sequence of $a$. Note that you'll notice that in my definition of a difference sequence it's the $(i+1)^{th}$ term not $i^{th}$ term of $\Lambda(a)=a_{i+1}-a{i}$

Comment: Why so fast in editing your question? I haven't defined summation sequence yet.

Comment: Thus, an alternative definition to $(2)$ would be : Let $\Omega$ map sequences to sequences such that $\Omega(a_{n})=a_{0}+a_{1}+\cdots +a_{n}$. We say that $\Omega^{k}(a)$ i.e. $\Omega$ composed with itself $k$ times, is the $k^{th}$ summation sequences of $a$ where $\Omega^{0}(a)=a$

Comment: @WiWo The answer to (1) is probably yes also. Just do my answer below with the pattern $x_1,x_2,\dots = K+1,K+1,K+2,K+1,K+2,K+3,K+1,K+2,K+3,K+4,\dots$.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to (2) is yes.

Consider the pattern $x_1,x_2,\dots = 1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,\dots$.

Our real-valued sequence will start off with $a_1 = 1$. With $a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}$ chosen, we choose $a_n$ so that $S_n(x_k) = S_{n-1}(x_k)$, which is possible, since $S_{n-1}(x_k)$ just depends on $a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}$ and since $S_n(x_k)$ depends linearly on $a_n$.

We claim the $K^{\text{th}}$ sum of $(a_n)_n$ is anti-cauchy for all $K \ge 1$. Indeed, fix $K \ge 1$, and just note that, by construction, we have $S_n(K) = S_{n-1}(K)$ for infinitely many $n$.

Comment: Can you rewrite your answer to include $(1)$?